# Text response displayed in a view's unbound label

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, label

I have a view that contains a submit button. When that submit button is clicked some code runs a process. I want to return a text message to a label on the view that will let the user know that their submission was successful or there was an error.

I've searched around and I have found many examples about labels but I haven't come across one that shows me how to do what I want.

My Controller:

```
public ActionResult Import()
{
    //Some code that runs a process
    //Need to know what code will return "Import was Successful" or "Erroring Importing"

    return RedirectToAction("Import")
}
```

My View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Import";
}

<h2>Import</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Importexcel", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <table>
        <tr><td>Import Files</td><td><input type="file" id="FileUpload1" name="FileUpload1" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" id="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" /></td></tr>
        **<tr><td>@Html.Label(returned results)</td></tr>** // Need to know how to do this

    </table>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view:

```
     @using (Html.BeginForm("Importexcel", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{ 

    <table>
    <tr><td>Import Files</td><td><input type="file" id="FileUpload1" name="FileUpload1" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" id="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" /></td></tr>
    **<tr><td>@Html.Label(returned results)</td></tr>** // Need to know how to do this

</table>  
    @ViewBag.Message
}
```

In your controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Import(){
    //Some code that runs a process
    //Need to know what code will return "Import was Successful" or "Erroring Importing"

    if(something){
     ViewBag.Message = "Import Failed";
    }
    else
    {
     ViewBag.Message = "Import Successful";
    }
        return View();
    }
```

Try and give that a shot.

Answer (score 0):

You can always pass either a key to a look-up table of messages or the message itself via the query string. Here's an example:

**Controller Action**

```
public ActionResult Import(string message = null)
{
    // Detect presence of message (i.e. !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(message)) and show it.
    // Additional logic after this...

    return RedirectToAction("Import", "YourControllerNameHere", new { message = "Your message here..." });
}
```

Then it's just a matter of wiring up your model or ViewModel  in the Import view so it displays the appropriate message.

Comment: Mario, Thanks for the quick response. I'm not using a Model or a ViewModel. My controller is doing all the work so there is no Model item for my label eg. @Html.Label(m => m.label). So how would I view the message? Would I code it like this? @Html.Label(message) is it that simple, or am i over thinking it?

Comment: You can store it in the `ViewBag`. For example, `ViewBag.Message = message;`. Then in your Razor view, write, `@ViewBag.Message`. You can wrap it with a `<span>` tag and set its `class` attribute to whatever style the message should have. Ideally, you would want to detect whether it's a successful status or not. Since `ViewBag` is a dynamic type, you can attach as many properties as you want. In this case, you can write, `ViewBag.Success = true;`